# How to make solvePnP return ALL possible solutions?

Tags: c++, opencv

Im trying to use `cv::solvePnP()` and `cv::solvePnPGeneric()` to get the position of the camera for each frame in a video, but I get to a frame where none of the returned solutions are near the previous solutions no matter what PnP function or flags I use. I know that there are more solutions to the PnP problem that are not returned becasue opencv deems them invalid. I want to create a custom version of `solvePnP()` that shows me these solutions as well.

I looked through the source code and traced all of the PnP function calls back to a funtion called `p3p::solve()` located [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/calib3d/src/p3p.cpp), but Im having trouble understanding where it filters out the invalid solutions.

Heres a snippet of the code where `nb_solutions` is the number of solutions and `...` signifys unspecified code.

```
int p3p::solve(double R[4][3][3], double t[4][3],
               double mu0, double mv0,   double X0, double Y0, double Z0,
               double mu1, double mv1,   double X1, double Y1, double Z1,
               double mu2, double mv2,   double X2, double Y2, double Z2,
               double mu3, double mv3,   double X3, double Y3, double Z3,
               bool p4p)
{
    ...
    int n = solve_for_lengths(lengths, distances, cosines);
    int nb_solutions = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        if (!align(M_orig, X0, Y0, Z0, X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, R[nb_solutions], t[nb_solutions]))
            continue;
        ...
        nb_solutions++;
    }
    ...
    return nb_solutions;
}

bool p3p::align(double M_end[3][3],
    double X0, double Y0, double Z0,
    double X1, double Y1, double Z1,
    double X2, double Y2, double Z2,
    double R[3][3], double T[3])
{
    ... // no other return statements!
    return true;
}
```

Why would `p3p::solve()` check the return value of `p3p::align()` if it always returns true?
And why does the number of solutions depend on that?

Comment: the solutions are stored in `R`, no?

Comment: Values of R are modified in that function. The return value is currently obsolete, but could be used in the future

Comment: the function p3p::solve(double R[4][3][3] ...) probably has the 4 different 3x3 solutions. So After returning from  p3p::solve you have solve candidates in the first variable. In function `bool p3p::solve(double R[3][3] ...)`you can see how the n different candidates are filtered and the one with the smalles reprojection error is chosen in `if (i == 0 || min_reproj > reproj) {
            ns = i;
            min_reproj = reproj;
        }`

Comment: sorry, my last comment was in a different opencv version. In your code links, in line 116 you can see that only the first (0-index) solution is chosen (`Rs[0]` and `ts[0]`)